# how to create tabcontrol from sql database data in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, tabcontrol

this is a continue from
[how to get database (sql) table names and colums in C# to combo and list box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821802/how-to-get-database-sql-table-names-and-colums-in-c-sharp-to-combo-and-list-bo)

my program now:
  1. connects to the database (microsoft SQL 2008/2012)
  2. shows the tables via ComboBox
  3. show table fields via ListBox
  4. show data via DataGridView

now i want to practice hash joins on 2 tables (tableA, tableB) but before that i want to desplay them.
i have a selection of hash functions to run on the data i have in the database (all integer) 
i want to split the tables into buckets and display them in windows using tabcontrol 
right now it's something simple (like if value 1 => tab 1, and ect...)

i have the idea on how to read the needed data from the database

but no idea on how to split it in the tabcontrol so each tab will only show it's relevant data

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: @marc_s i use microsoft sql server 08/12